# Best HTTP Authorization header type for JWT

Tags: http-headers, jwt

I'm wondering what is the best appropriate `Authorization` HTTP header type for [JWT tokens](http://jwt.io/).

One of the probably most popular type is `Basic`. For instance:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

It handle two parameters such as a login and a password. So it is not relevant for JWT tokens.

Also, I heard about *Bearer* type, for instance:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

However, I don't know its meaning. Is it related to bears?

Is there a particular way to use JWT tokens in the HTTP `Authorization` header? Should we use `Bearer`, or should we simplify and just use:

```
Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Or maybe, just a `JWT` HTTP header:

```
JWT: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

Answer (score 430):

The best HTTP header for your client to send an access token (JWT or any other token) is the `Authorization` header with the `Bearer` authentication scheme.

This scheme is described by the [RFC6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

Example:

```
GET /resource HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIXVCJ9TJV...r7E20RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

If you need stronger security protection, you may also consider the following IETF draft: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-pop-architecture. This draft seems to be a good alternative to the (abandoned?) https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac.

Note that even if this RFC and the above specifications are related to the OAuth2 Framework protocol, they can be used in any other contexts that require a token exchange between a client and a server.

Unlike the custom `JWT` scheme you mention in your question, [the `Bearer` one is registered at the IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml).

Concerning the `Basic` and `Digest` authentication schemes, they are dedicated to authentication using a username and a secret (see [RFC7616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616) and [RFC7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617)) so not applicable in that context.

Comment: Thank you! Good to see the origin of this `Bearer` keyword. But it comes from OAuth. However JWT can be used without OAuth. It's totally independent with OAuth specs.

Comment: Yes it comes from the OAuth2 framework protocole, but can be used in any other context. Your server is free to accept JWT using other headers or ways (e.g. in the body request or in the query string), but the `Authenticate` header more appropriate and is compliant with the [RFC7235](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235) which describes an authentication framework in a HTTP 1.1 context

Comment: I agree with Zag zag, a custom scheme like "JWT" seems way more appropriate than coercing the OAuth2 Bearer scheme into this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Quoting https://jwt.io/introduction/: "the user agent should send the JWT, typically in the Authorization header using the Bearer schema. The content of the header should look like the following: Authorization: Bearer <token>"

Comment: If it helps somebody - I came here looking for this example: - curl request using Bearer scheme: `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" <the rest of your curl cmd>`

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as so, the one marked as the accepted answer was obviously marked as it quickly solved the OP's problem, however in terms of JWT it's very, very bad advice, this answer however is the correct advice.

Comment: One doubt tho, should the token be encoded in base64?

Comment: All tokens shall be url safe encoded. If it is at JWS/JWE, it already uses safe encoding by design (base64url-safe), but if you use another token type, you have to make sure it is suitable for us in the header parameter (e.g. hex is ok but a binary string is not). See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2

Answer (score 126):

### Short answer

The `Bearer` authentication scheme is what you are looking for.

### Long answer

> Is it related to bears?

Errr... No :)

According to the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bearer), here's the definition of *bearer*:

> **bearer** <sub><sup>*/ˈbɛːrə/*</sup></sub>
> *noun*
>
> 1. A person or thing that carries or holds something.
> 2. A person who presents a cheque or other order to pay money.

The first definition includes the following synonyms: *messenger*, *agent*, *conveyor*, *emissary*, *carrier*, *provider*.

And here's the definition of *bearer token* according to the [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750):

> [**1.2. Terminology**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-1.2)
>
> **Bearer Token**
>
> A security token with the property that any party in possession of the token (a "bearer") can use the token in any way that any other party in possession of it can. Using a bearer token does not require a bearer to prove possession of cryptographic key material (proof-of-possession).

The `Bearer` authentication scheme is [registered in IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) and originally defined in the [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) for the OAuth 2.0 authorization framework, but nothing stops you from using the `Bearer` scheme for access tokens in applications that don't use OAuth 2.0.

Stick to the standards as much as you can and don't create your own authentication schemes.

---

An access token must be sent in the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) request header using the `Bearer` authentication scheme:

> [**2.1.  Authorization Request Header Field**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1)
>
> When sending the access token in the `Authorization` request header field defined by HTTP/1.1, the client uses the `Bearer` authentication scheme to transmit the access token.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> GET /resource HTTP/1.1
> Host: server.example.com
> Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Clients SHOULD make authenticated requests with a bearer token using the `Authorization` request header field with the `Bearer` HTTP authorization scheme. [...]

In case of invalid or missing token, the `Bearer` scheme should be included in the [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.1) response header:

> [**3.  The WWW-Authenticate Response Header Field**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3)
>
> If the protected resource request does not include authentication credentials or does not contain an access token that enables access to the protected resource, the resource server MUST include the HTTP `WWW-Authenticate` response header field [...].
>
> All challenges defined by this specification MUST use the auth-scheme value `Bearer`.  This scheme MUST be followed by one or more auth-param values. [...].
>
> For example, in response to a protected resource request without authentication:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="example"
> ```
>
> And in response to a protected resource request with an authentication attempt using an expired access token:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="example",
>                          error="invalid_token",
>                          error_description="The access token expired"
> ```

Comment: Yes. It is related to bears. In the same way that python is related to snakes. Duh.

Comment: Bears.. That does it. Thank you for making my day.

Comment: Is it a vulnerability if : i give the user the token, but when he wants to send me a request he must send the token back in the request body? I will then get it from there and validate? I dont really have other options, as the way they send the request isnt defined by me, but i would be interested if that is any bad or if theres a solution to make it more secure.

Comment: @DanielJeney did you find an answer

Comment: Bears. Beets. Battlestar Galactica.

Comment: @DanielJeney It's generally not advisable to come up with your own, non-standard security scheme, but a HTTPS request body is not less secure than a HTTPS request header, so sending the JWT in the body should be OK. See here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97851/https-post-request-header-versus-request-body