# Verify a JWT token string, containing 'Bearer ' with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jwt

I send a header in a recommended form `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.

As it looks, token string, which is `'Bearer <token>'`, is not a token, but needs the `'Bearer '` substring to be removed first to get the token string itself.

I wonder, if it's a regular practice to remove it manually from code, like this:

```
const token = authHeaderValue.replace('Bearer ', '')
```

before decoding and verifying it?

Why do I need this `'Bearer '` string in my custom application?

Comment: refer to this: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/120244

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The value `Bearer` in the HTTP [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header indicates the authentication scheme, just like `Basic` and `Digest`. It's defined in the [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

An application can support multiple authentication schemes, so it's always recommended to check the authentication schema first.

In a token based authentication, first ensure that the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header contains the `Bearer` string followed by a space. If not, refuse the request. If `Bearer` followed by a space has been found, extract the token that must be just after the space character.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157391/1426227) for further details on the `Bearer` authentication scheme.

Comment: the use of the "jwt" package is vital to this answer, and yet that's not even mentioned nor covered in the code.  This sort of omission helps no-one, the code provided is partial for the sake of a single require/import statement.  For anyone who needs it the package is actually called "jsonwebtoken" and you need to install it into your project with "npm i jsonwebtoken" (or use yarn add) and then add the line "const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');" at the top of your code.

Answer (score 24):

I use this technique.

```js
// Header names in Express are auto-converted to lowercase
let token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers['authorization']; 

// Remove Bearer from string
token = token.replace(/^Bearer\s+/, "");

if (token) {
  jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Token is not valid'
      });
    }
    req.decoded = decoded;
    next();
  });
} else {
  return res.json({
    success: false,
    message: 'Token not provided'
  });
}
```

Here we are stripping off any Bearer string in front of JWT, using a regular expression. If any whitespace is included, it is stripped too.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication header request have a format defined in IETF.

i.e. Authentication :

Type consists of following: Bearer, error_code, error_description.

We can send several types at once by delimiting it by ',' character.

Bearer is an Authentication access type.

Reference: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#page-14

Answer (score 0):

i use split function to extract token

```
const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
if(! bearerHeader ){
    return res.sendStatus(403);
}
else
{
    const bearerToken = bearerHeader.split(' ')[1];
    let data = await jwt.verify(bearerToken,secretkey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

const bearerToken = token.split(' ')[1];

Here is the solution. And it will fix your issue. You just need to split function.  And in code given below, i show you when to use split function for a specific token.

Cheers!

verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
res.header(
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
"*"
);
let token = req.headers["authorization"];

```
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).send({ message: "No token provided!" });
  }
  
  **const bearerToken = token.split(' ')[1];**  Here is the solution. And it will fix your issue. You just need to split function.   

  jwt.verify(bearerToken, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).send({ message: "Unauthorized Token!" });
    }
    req.userId = decoded.id;
    req.token = token;
    next();
  });
};
```