# JWT / JSON Web Token: Safe to pass the token in the body on creation?

Tags: jwt

I'm new to JWT. I have an endpoint for session creation. A request is made by my mobile app. Currently I have it so that when a user signs in successfully, I return the JWT in the Authorization Bearer header:

```
new_conn
|> put_status(:created)
|> put_resp_header("authorization", "Bearer #{jwt}") #<-----------
|> render("show.json", session: user)
```

However, this is a little tricky to read from my client side. Is it safe for me to return it in the JSON response instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When the client sends their credentials to the server (to exchange them for a token), the recently issued token can be returned in the response payload as text or as JSON, it's up to you:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 09:51:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain

xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 09:51:12 GMT
Content-Type: application/json

{ "token" : "xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz" }
```

What you must keep in mind is the communication between client and server: It must be done over HTTPS to ensure that the message won't be tampered with.

---

And when the client sends the token to the server, it should be sent in the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header (again over HTTPS):

```
GET /api/greetings HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Authorization: Bearer xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz
```

The [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header is supposed to carry *credentials*. And when talking about an authentication schema based on tokens, the tokens are *credentials* and frequently prefixed with `Bearer`, that indicates the authentication schema. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157391/1426227) will shed some light on this.

Finally, it is worthwhile to mention that the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header is designed to be used in the *request* and not in the *response*.

Comment: Actually https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-10.3.1 defines `application/jwt` for plain tokens. Using it could simplify the token management by a filter targeting this specific content type.