# Token Based Authentication Web API in ASP.NET Core using jwt

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token, role-base-authorization

I am doing Token Based Authentication Web API in ASP.NET Core using jwt. I can't understand why we need to use Bearer keyword in `[Authorize("Bearer")]` attribute on above the action method for authorization and i am not be able to do authorization role base or simple as in attached screenshot.[image]

see the below code

```
 // GET api/values
    [Authorize("Bearer")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

i am following [this link](https://mejdiradhouani.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/token-based-authentication-web-api-using-asp-net-core/) to do the authorization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best HTTP Authorization header type for JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265812/best-http-authorization-header-type-for-jwt)

Comment: No.  I want to use role base authentication and authorization like i want to use [Authorize(Role="Admin")]

Comment: Strange, I don't have to use `Bearer` keyword and it all works fine for me. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52822924/5374333