# how to Remove Bearer in JWT Auth In VPS server

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I want to Remove **Bearer** in JWT token while it's come from mobile side
in my VPS server Required Bearer otherwise it's throws error **Token is Required**
how can i handle this for remove Bearer in **Authorization**.

Comment: Which gaurd are you using? Auth:api?

Comment: Your question is quite vague, please include some relevant code or an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265812/best-http-authorization-header-type-for-jwt