# Alamofire POST Error Token - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, post, alamofire

my company and I are working on a iOS Project, and we get stacked in this issue. We are trying to make a POST request to our API, but all we are getting is a success code but with a reponse of type:

> SUCCESS: {
>       detail = "Authentication credentials were not provided.";
>   }

Here is our code:

```
@IBAction func accept(_ sender: Any) {
    var comm,cat,dist : String!
    comm = observationstwee.text!
    print(comm)
    let catd = 7
    cat = String(catd)
    print(cat)
    dist = distancetwee.text!
    print(dist)
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "comment":comm,
        "category":cat,
        "distance":dist,
        "timestamp":time
    ]
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Token \(token!)"]
    print(headers.debugDescription)
    Alamofire.request("https://llegoelbigotes.ubiqme.es/api/new-travel",parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON {response in switch(response.result) {

    case .success(_):
        print(response)
        print("Correct Travel")
        //changeViewController(storyboard_name: "Main", viewcontroller_name: "tabBarController", context: self)
        break

    case .failure(_):
        print("FAILURE")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help we are working with Alamofire 4.5 and iOS 11.2

Comment: check the name of the autorization key

Comment: check  your token has a value and check how your endpoint handles authorisation. try using the postman google extension to send the request via that and see if it works. if it doesnt then the issue is with the API rather than your code

Comment: maybe you need to use different scheme, based on how your api layer implemented, please check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265812/best-http-authorization-header-type-for-jwt. Maybe try using Bearer vs Token

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work.

```
let url = "https://llegoelbigotes.ubiqme.es/api/new-travel"

Alamofire.request(
        url,
        method: .post,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
        headers: headers). validate().responseJSON{ response in 
        switch(response.result) {

        case .success(_):
            print(response.response)
            print("Correct Travel")
           //changeViewController(storyboard_name: "Main", viewcontroller_name: "tabBarController", context: self)
           break

        case .failure(_):
        print("FAILURE")
     }
 }
```

If not then try to check your **headers** variable of type **HTTPHeaders**

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Token \(token!)"]
```

As here you are appending **Token** with your token string. say your token is **XXXX** then it becomes **TokenXXXX**. Try using it like

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": " \(token!)"]
```

Then Check.

Comment: Not workin, getting Alamofire.AFError.responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(403)) @Yaseen

Comment: The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code that means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason. Try printing out everything before making the POST call you might have issues with your Token. I suggest, try doing the POST call via POSTMAN or  [hurl](https://www.hurl.it).

Answer (score 0):

1) You are sending GET request. I don't see in Alamofire call specified another method and, AFAIK, default is GET.

2) Chain validate() method before responseJSON so your request call will look like this:

```
Alamofire.request("https://llegoelbigotes.ubiqme.es/api/new-travel", method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { ...
```

Another possible fix to this problem is using another encoding. In your call to alamofire set `encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody)`

Check [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-validation) out for more information.