# Why subtract the first 7 characters from token

Tags: authentication, jwt, token

I am looking to  know why we subtract the first 7 token characters  during authentication, as in:

```
substr($_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"],7)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this example: [Best HTTP Authorization header type for JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265812/best-http-authorization-header-type-for-jwt#33281233)

The HTTP header is like that (on one line):

> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIXVCJ9...TJVA95OrM7E20RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ

So you need to remove the "Bearer " part which is 7 characters long plus one for the space, but since in most languages things are indexed starting at 0, in the above string the token starts at position 7.

See https://jwt.io/introduction/ for more explanations on the header content.