# Getting the API Key from ServiceStack request

Tags: servicestack

Have a simple get Customer api that's returning list of customers fine.

Setting up for service to service authentication, if I make this [Authenticated] and try to implement using ApiKeyAuthProvider, the req.GetApiKey returns null and I get an error;

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:44347/api/customers application/json 0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:2019-07-01 16:50:34,004 [16] INFO  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:44347/api/customers application/json 0
The thread 0x42cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x302c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost:2019-07-01 17:01:14,601 [16] ERROR ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost - ServiceBase<TRequest>::Service Exception
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at ServiceStack.Host.HttpRequestAuthentication.GetBasicAuth(IRequest httpReq) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\HttpRequestAuthentication.cs:line 45
   at ServiceStack.Host.HttpRequestAuthentication.GetBasicAuthUserAndPassword(IRequest httpReq) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\HttpRequestAuthentication.cs:line 50
   at ServiceStack.Auth.ApiKeyAuthProvider.PreAuthenticate(IRequest req, IResponse res) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Auth\ApiKeyAuthProvider.cs:line 232
   at ServiceStack.AuthenticateAttribute.PreAuthenticate(IRequest req, IEnumerable`1 authProviders) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\AuthenticateAttribute.cs:line 96
   at ServiceStack.AuthenticateAttribute.ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, Object requestDto) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\AuthenticateAttribute.cs:line 74
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, Object instance, TRequest requestDto) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\ServiceRunner.cs:line 127
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 640574.8754ms 400 application/json; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:2019-07-01 17:01:14,607 [16] INFO  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request finished in 640574.8754ms 400 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Clearly I have missed something obvious...any pointers appreciated.

```
// Register ORMLite connection
                container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);

                //Tell ServiceStack you want to persist User Auth Info in SQL Server
                container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(dbFactory));

                // See https://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider
                Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
                    new IAuthProvider[] {
                        new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings) {
                            SessionCacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                            AllowInHttpParams = true,       // Whether to allow API Keys in 'apikey' QueryString or FormData (e.g. `?apikey={APIKEY}`) 
                            RequireSecureConnection = true,
                        },
                    }
                ) { 
                    IncludeRegistrationService = true, 
                });

                GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
                {
                    LastApiKey = req.GetApiKey();
                });
```

Request

```
POST https://localhost:44347/api/customers HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44347
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2
Accept: application/json
Origin: https://localhost:44347
Authorization: yDOr26HsxyhpuRB3qbG07qfCmDhqutnA-yDOr26HsxyhpuRB3qbG07qfCmDhqutnA-yDOr26HsxyhpuRB3qbG07qfCmDhqutnA
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://localhost:44347/swagger-ui/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8

{}
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept,Origin
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5.50 NetCore/Windows
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
X-Startup-Errors: 1
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcUmVwb3NcTUJXZWJccnZhcGlcUnZXZWJcUnZBcGlcYXBpXGN1c3RvbWVycw==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2019 08:07:40 GMT

13e
{"responseStatus":{"errorCode":"ArgumentOutOfRangeException","message":"Length cannot be less than zero.\r\nParameter name: length","errors":[{"errorCode":"ArgumentOutOfRangeException","fieldName":"length","message":"Length cannot be less than zero.\r\n"}]},"responseCreatedUtcDateTime":"2019-07-03T08:07:40.7955827Z"}
0
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the HTTP Request/Response headers containing the Auth Key, scrub out any confidential info with `xxxx`.

Comment: Ok making sure I put Bearer in front of the toke gets me passed the Length zero error (checking the code on github helped me debug that), so now I get error in ORMLiteAuthRepositoryBase.

Comment: ERROR ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost - ServiceBase<TRequest>::Service Exception Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(ReadOnlySpan`1 str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(ReadOnlySpan`1 s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at ServiceStack.Auth.OrmLiteAuthRepositoryBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<GetUserAuth>b__0(IDbConnection db) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Server\Auth\OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs:line 397

Answer (score 1):

Your client is sending an invalid Authorization Bearer Token, it needs to have the [Authroization Bearer Token format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157391/85785):

```
Authorization: Bearer {Token}
```

If you're sending an [Authenticated API Key or JWT Request via Open API](https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi#swagger-ui-security) it needs to have the [Bearer prefix as per the Open API docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi#swagger-ui-security):

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks - a few errors on my part along the way.  Thanks, sorted now and working.

Answer (score 0):

OK I had manually created a User and APIKey in the underlying tables and had used a UserAuthId 'SomeAuthId' i.e. letter in them, and the ORM repository code is expecting these to be integers.  Its cool that I can see the code in github and debug this myself - thanks for the comment as it got me thinking and looking into my Auth setup.

Comment: The API Key tables should be automatically [created by the ApiKeyAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/1c8b47335a0563de03c26270b417125b884c7c2e/src/ServiceStack/Auth/ApiKeyAuthProvider.cs#L344) if it doesn't exist, you shouldn't be trying to create it yourself.