# How should I use android Tokens?

Tags: https

```
url = new URL("https://blb-test.morulabs.com/api/fetch/cosmetics/");
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
```

Is it correct to put the token value like that in the requestproperty for token authentication to communicate with the server? 400 Communication Error

Answer (score 0):

I can't add this answer as a comment (not enough reputation).

Similar question was answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265812/best-http-authorization-header-type-for-jwt).

If you authentication was failing, I would expected a 401 error, instead of 400 you received. The 400 error means that a the peer received something unexpected.
More information can be checked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning).

You must check with the peer to understand what is the correct way to pass this attributes to them.