# What is the motivation in using "Token" as authentication scheme in django rest framework?

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, http-authentication

Django rest framework provides a [TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) class for authentication. It validates against header in the format of `Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b`. The authentication scheme, `Token`, seems customarily chosen. The [iana auth scheme registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml)'s list of
authentication scheme name does not include `Token` as of today (2019-12-20).

Two background RFCs not mentioned in the above iana link:

- [rfc-2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.8) mentions Basic and Digest Access only.
- [rfc-2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3) mentions `Basic` is not secure

So my questions are

- Is it a custom scheme, if so
- How common is it to use custom auth scheme in `Authorization` header
- What is the motivation in choosing `Token` as the scheme
- What other libraries also use `Token` as the scheme

To complicate matter, [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt) provides a [JWT authentication class](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py#L71) , which adopt `JWT` as the scheme. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265812/best-http-authorization-header-type-for-jwt), the correct choice is `Bearer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IANA auth scheme is more recent (2014 on the linked document) that when the Token has been implemented (2012 according to [this PR](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/249)).
Things have changed since but migrating would be a lot of work and there are better alternatives now.