# Axios cannot send request with cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to fetch data from my api, I need to pass a cookie in the header. I tested on postman, and it works, but I does not work in my code, the return error is 403. Any ideas what I am missing ?

Thanks

here is my code:

```js
function LoadStudies() {

    const config = {
    
        headers: { 
            Cookie: '_ga=GA1.2.2139220028.1611912340;csrftoken=ADJBapIX3oLu3j8QHdD05zsJnDhzx0jDYtAjKV2GY0FkBzVNfdLY8xVMV1YF4Ibd;djdt=show;sessionid=0x40wumk8ehcb4boh6610pqud5wtqsjl;session_state=4f7e11af-abd0-4f9f-8357-611100821df3' 
        },
        withCredentials :true,
   
    }
    console.log(config)
    axios
        .get("https://Domain/api/study/", config)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('working!')
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });

}

LoadStudies();
```

Comment: error 403 means restricted access, maybe the problem comes from your API and not from your front-end

Comment: but it does work with postman so it should not be a problem with the api isnt't ?

Comment: yeah since it worked in postman its not an api problem

Comment: `withCredentials :true,` I don't see any credentials being set in your example.

Comment: yeah it does not change anything, i tried to remove it ... same

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming you are running this client-side, in a browser, given the tag:reactjs] tag).

`Cookie` is a [forbidden header name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name).

You can't set the header manually with client-side JavaScript. You must have an existing cookie (which will then be sent if you have `withCredentials: true`).

If you are making a *same origin* request you could set it via [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), otherwise you will have to make an HTTP request (with `withCredentials: true`) and have the API set the cookie (browser restrictions on 3rd-party cookies may cause problems here though).

---

Note that APIs are generally stateless, so it is quite odd that you are trying to send cookies with a Google Analytics ID, a session ID, and a csrftoken. Generally you would just be sending an authorisation token, which is commonly a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) these days, and often in the [`Authorization` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265812/best-http-authorization-header-type-for-jwt) rather than a Cookie.