# How do I authenticate with JWT using gRPC for PHP?

Tags: php, authentication, jwt, metadata, grpc

I've generated my client code from proto files. Now I'm trying to connect but get the `'jwt' is not located at the context` error from server. Here's what I do:

```php
$myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient(
    "$host:$port",
    [
        'credentials' => ChannelCredentials::createInsecure(),
        'update_metadata' => function ($metaData) use ($token) {
//            $metaData['authorization'] = ['jwt' . $token]; // doesn't work
//            $metaData['authorization']['jwt'] = $token; // doesn't work
//            $metaData['jwt'] = $token; // doesn't work
            $metaData['authorization'] = ['Bearer ' . $token]; // doesn't work

            return $metaData;
        },
    ]
);
$unaryCall = $myServiceClient->MyMethod(new MyMethodRequest());
$wait = $unaryCall->wait();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```php
$myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient(
    "$host:$port",
    [
        'credentials' => ChannelCredentials::createInsecure(),
        'update_metadata' => function ($metaData) use ($token) {
            $metaData['jwt'] = [$token];

            return $metaData;
        },
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
$myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient(
    "$host:$port",
    [
        'credentials' => ChannelCredentials::createInsecure(),
        'update_metadata' => function ($metaData) use ($token) {
            $metaData['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' . $token; 
            return $metaData;
        },
    ]
);
```

[Best HTTP Authorization header type for JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265812/best-http-authorization-header-type-for-jwt)

Or like this:

https://jwt.io/introduction

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```